# How can I delete integers from list (of integers and strings) by taking which value to delete from user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, remove-method

I am doing a menu driven program in python to insert and delete items in a list. I have a list containing integers and strings. I want to delete integer.

So I take input from user as

```
list = [1, 2, 3, "hi", 5]
x = input("enter the value to be deleted")
# input is given as 2 
list.remove(x)
```

But it gives me a `ValueError`

I typecasted the input to int and it worked for integers but not for the string.

Comment: will you ever remove the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It gives you an error because you want to remove `int`, but your input is `str`. Your code will work only if input is `'hi'`.

Try this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, "hi", 5]
x = input("enter the value to be deleted")  # x is a str!

if x.isdigit():  # check if x can be converted to int
    x = int(x)  

arr.remove(x)  # remove int OR str if input is not supposed to be an int ("hi")
```

And please don't use **list** as a variable name, because `list` is a function and a data type.

Comment: So python doesn't do duck-typing (coercion)? Or is the strict typing specific to `remove`?

Comment: It is specific to `input()`, it will always produce a `str`. And yes, strict type is required to `remove()`.

Comment: Thanks! Ivan Vinogradov.

Comment: @Nisarg I've adjusted the code to work with strings, check it out and choose an answer!

Comment: Thanks for an alternate Solution @Elvir Muslic

Answer (score 0):

Works with `'hi'` as input too.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, "hi", 5]


by_index = input('Do you want to delete an index: yes/no ')
bool_index = False
x = input("enter the value/index to be deleted ")


if by_index.lower() == 'yes':
    del(list[int(x)])

elif by_index.lower() == 'no':
    if x.isdigit():
        x = int(x)
    del(list[list.index(x)])

else:
    print('Error!')


print(list)
```

> [1, 2, 3, 5]

Comment: ‘list.remove(x)’ works well both on strings and integers. So if-else clause here is redundant.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov Yeah, the OP probably thought that two answers can be marked. . I didn't mean to steal your answer title! You got the awesome and fast responses! Thank you for your service, I've changed my code. `remove` = removes the first matching value vs `del` we can either delete it by index or extract the index and then delete it